# How to always focus keep focus in text box

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a single HTML page that contains two divs. The div on the left (90% of page) is the target for ajax results. The div on the right (10% of page) contains a single text box.

The idea for the page is to enter a part number to the text box (via a barcode scanner) and display the drawing which matches that part number, show up in the left div.

I have all of that working. No problems there.

What I can't figure out, is how to return the focus to the textbox after the drawing loads.

The drawing is being loaded as an object, like this:

```
<div id="viz">
      <object classid="clsid:A662DA7E-CCB7-4743-B71A-D817F6D575DF" width="640" height="480">
         <param name="src" value="name_of_file.dwf" />
         <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
         <param name="UserInterfaceEnabled" value="false" />
         <param name="NavigatorDocked" value="true" />
         <param name="ToolbarVisible" value="false" />
         <embed width="100%" height="100%" wmode="transparent" src="<?php echo $drawingfullpath;?>" ></embed>
      </object>
</div>
```

(For anyone keeping score, that object is Autodesk DWF viewer. it acts a lot like flash, but doesn't accept all of the same parameters).

What is the best way to always keep focus in the text box? Because the operator will be using a barcode scanner, I'd rather not have them require a mouse to click back into the text box if focus is lost.

I would prefer to not use jquery, as it seems like overkill for such a simple request. HOWEVER, if jquery is the *only* way to accomplish this, then that's fine.

---

### update

fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/g9YxB/7/) has been updated with the latest suggestion from @subin.

The focus is still lost once the object loads. HOWEVER, if you click away from the page and then click back, the focus is where it belongs (in the text box). That has to be a clue, right?

Comment: can u set up a fiddle

Comment: Use jQuery : $("#textbox").focus();

Comment: How does the loading happen? Is the input box in a form that's targetted to a frame, or is it an AJAX mechanism?

Comment: Here is a fiddle of the whole page. The PHP, just spits back the "viz" object, shown above. http://jsfiddle.net/g9YxB/

Comment: @Pointy the input box is just a box, onchange calls the ajax function to return the data from php page.

Comment: @Edward There shouldn't be any HTML tags in Java Script textarea of JsFiddle

Comment: could you try if that works for you? http://jsfiddle.net/Glutamat/z5JHj/

Comment: The function `.focus()` is a jQuery one...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using jQuery would look something like this:

```
$(function() {
     // Focus on load
     $('.scanner').focus();
     // Force focus
     $('.scanner').focusout(function(){
         $('.scanner').focus();
     });
     // Ajax Stuff
     $('.scanner').change(function() {
         $.ajax({
             async: true,
             cache: false,
             type: 'post',
             url: '/echo/html/',
             data: {
                 html: '<p>This is your object successfully loaded here.</p>'
             },
             dataType: 'html',
             beforeSend: function() {
                 window.alert('Scanning code');
             },
             success: function(data) {
                 window.alert('Success');
                 $('.objectWrapper').append(data);
             },
             // Focus
             complete: function() {
                 $('.scanner').val('').focus();
             }
        });
    });
});
```

jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/laelitenetwork/fuMYX/5/

Comment: Thanks for posting that. I changed it to call my php page and send along $('.scanner').val(), it's returning the drawing (as it should be), but again is stealing the focus. 

Once the drawing loads, you can tell it has the focus because pressing (alt) produces menu shortcuts (inside of object).. I'm starting to feel like this is a lost cause.

Comment: Hello Edward, I'm afraid it's maybe related to the embedded object rather than the code you're using to force the focus. It's known some objects "steal" focus from other elements and keep it for them please check reference [1].

I'm not 100% sure but you could try replacing _embed_ by **object** as shown in [Embed Viewers](http://www.autodesk.com.hk/adsk/servlet/item?siteID=1170102&id=7018784) point #2, and see if it works.

References:
[1] [The IE embed dwf viewer steals focus](http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/DWF-Viewer/The-IE-embed-dwf-viewer-steals-focus/td-p/1560857)

Comment: I ended up marking this as the answer because it's the most thorough response. In the end, I believe @Jose is correct. it's the embedded object and not the code.

Answer (score 4):

Use setInterval :

```
setInterval(function(){
 var focusbox;
 focusbox = document.getElementById("part_to_search");
 focusbox.focus();
});
```

Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/g9YxB/10/

Comment: I think the key question is how, when, and where the re-focus should occur. In other words, where exactly should this code go? (*edit* also, congratulations on learning to program at such a young age :)

Comment: I don't understand why people keep suggesting to use jQuery for simple tasks like this.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but this isnt' working. It works on pageload, but once the object loads, the focus never returns to the text box. If I click somewhere else on the page (not on the object) then the cursor returns to the text box. But if I don't click off the object, then the focus will never return to the text box.

Comment: @Edward Updated answer with Java script and a jsfiddle demo

Comment: No dice. I updated the question to include the latest information available.

Comment: @Edward Updated again.