# jQuery focus not allowing moving out

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery `.focus()` to make a textbox receive focus if the input is incorrect. But when the textbox receives focus, it can't lose it. I want the user to be able to select other textboxes too. How can I do this?

```
function checkpassword() {
  var password = $("#password").val();
  var password2 = $("#password-reenter").val();
if(password != null){
  if (password === password2) {
    //alert("Passwords match");

    $("#password-reenter").css('border','1px solid gray');
    $("#password-warning").hide();
    $("#password, #password-reenter").next('span').removeClass().addClass('ui-icon ui-icon-check');
  } else {

    $("#password-reenter").attr('title','The passwords do not match. Please reenter the password.').css('border','3px solid red').focus();


  }
}
};
```

Comment: It's probably being triggered more than once, what triggers the incorrect validation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to always focus keep focus in text box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19495831/how-to-always-focus-keep-focus-in-text-box)

Comment: @dave, I want to do the exact opposite. How is this a _duplicate_?

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood the question. You've replied to at least two people now that they have provided exactly the opposite of what you want, but I still can't comprehend what that is. I think you should clarify the question.

Comment: @dave, i don't want it to keep focus, i want it to gain focus, but not so that nothing else can gain focus. I gave the page that it was on in a comment to the first answer. Look there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No problem found...

You probably have other code out there triggering the focus.

Check the snippet:

```js
$("#password-reenter")
  .attr('title','The passwords do not match. Please reenter thepassword.')
  .css('border','3px solid red').focus();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="password-reenter" />
<input type="text" />
```

**EDIT:**

After looking at your code (given in a comment) I found this:

```
<input type="password" name="password-reenter" id="password-reenter" onfocusout="checkpassword()" style="font-family: latine; border: 3px solid red;" required="" title="The passwords do not match. Please reenter the password.">
```

As you can see the `onfocusout="checkpassword()"` cause your problem because it calls the `checkpassword()` that will focus again if the passwords don't match.

Comment: The `.focus()` is linked to an `if` statement. Does that make any difference? [Here](http://sarkelliancreed.comule.com/account.php) is the page:

Answer (score 0):

You are validating everytime the element loses focus. If you click everywhere else it will lose focus, validate again and refocus the element. This way, the user will only be able to focus on another element if he enters the corrent value and pass the validation.

You can:

1. Don't force focus. The element gets a red border, the user will notice.
2. Use a class to put the invalid styling, this way you can check if the element has the class and only focus when you put the class. Eg. http://jsfiddle.net/04dcje0m/

   ```
   $('#element').on('blur', function (e) {

       if (this.value !== $('#password').val()) {

           if (this.className != 'invalid') {

               this.focus();

           }

           this.className = 'invalid';

       } else {

           this.className = '';

       }

   });
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Try use blur.

```
$("#password-reenter")
  .attr('title','The passwords do not match. Please reenter thepassword.')
  .css('border','1px solid 000000').blur();
```

Comment: Maybe, but that is completely the opposite of what I want.